# Kendo UI treeview child node without checkbox

Tags: checkbox, kendo-ui, treeview

I do not need checkbox for child node only for "items" without children. i.e.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We used the Template function in kendo treeview:

```
 .Template("<input  type='checkbox' name='checkedNodes' tabindex='-1' #= (item.HasChildren === false) ? '' : '' # #= item.HasChildren ?  '': 'hidden' #  id='_#= item.uid #'   />"
```